# Best way to get a walk through review?

Tags: discussion

After creating several puzzles in the past, one of them grew to be enormous, detailed, and convoluted. As a result, it became obvious that it needed a walkthrough as a guide to those that might stumble upon it in the future. The puzzle was solved, and a first draft of that walkthrough has been completed. However, the magnitude of both the puzzle and walkthrough has prompted me to search out for help in reviewing the guide.

**What is the best way to get a critique of a puzzle walkthrough?**

**Reference:**

- [Justice and Fairness: Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6212/justice-and-fairness-part-1)
- [Justice and Fairness: Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9749/justice-and-fairness-part-2)
- [Justice and Fairness Walkthrough](http://pastebin.com/mYH6B84G)

The walkthrough can be copied but will expire in one month. This is to prevent it from becoming the de facto reference for the guide. Those wishing to give a critique should note that any changes to formatting should be text-based only. Markdown would be acceptable, but rich formatting would not due to how it will be presented in the future. Other markup languages could be used such as HTML, but simpler is better.

Comment: Wait, didn't you post a meta question about this already? This looks awfully familiar...

Answer (score 4):

I think a full review of the walkthrough may be outside the scope of this site, and would fall under "too broad." To get a sense of why, I'll point to the fact that the guide is 23,055 words long (roughly, depending on what you call a "word"), and is about seven times the maximum length Stack Exchange will let you post. Asking a question of such magnitude, even if it were possible, would be well outside the scope of what Stack Exchange - or honestly, most of us - could feasibly do.

To get a critique of your puzzle walkthrough, instead, I'd recommend posting a particular section of the puzzle walkthrough - or maybe two - instead. That will allow more specific feedback on something you think sits on less stable ground. I've skimmed the guide - 23,000 words is a lot to read; forgive me - and I do think there's room for feedback, but particular sections or specific feedback on how to structurally organize a section may be ideal in this case.